# FileInfo проверить 2 пути файла на существование

Tags: c#

Есть 2 файла на проверку, как проверить эти  2 файла одновременно?, если какой-нибудь файл существует продолжить  метод.

```
FileInfo origFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test.txt");
FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test2.txt");

if (Здесь проверить origFile и destFile)
{
   // Какой-то файл если существует продолжаем.
}
```

Comment: например `origFile.Exists() && destFile.Exists()`, но тут другой вопрос, что вы потом хотите с ними делать. Потому что такая проверка не дает гарантии, что файл будет существовать после того, как вы выполните проверку и тем более не гарантирует, что у вас достаточно прав на работу с этими файлами.

Comment: @rdorn,Вот что я делать хочу, проверить эти файлы и если какой-нибудь из них существует, прочитать  тот файл который есть.

Comment: тогда просто заверните чтение в try..catch, и если первый дал сбой, в catch поднимаете флаг, о состоянию флага читайте второй. В любом случае чтение файла без обработки исключений делать не стоит,так что тут предварительная проверка лишняя. Проверять на существование имеет смысл после операции создания файла, например для повторения операции, если проверка не пройдена.

Comment: @rdorn, Проверил Ваш способ, не работает, а что делает это                 `if (origFile.Exists != destFile.Exists)` способ?

Comment: эм... а вы точно условие правильно скопировали? потому что, то что вы сейчас написали `if (origFile.Exists != destFile.Exists)` в принципе смысла особого не имеет. А у меня в первом комментарии опечатка сорри, скобочки лишние, Exists свойство а не метод.

Comment: @rdorn, Да я без скобок писал, у меня компилятор всё видет =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно прочитать данные только из одного файла

```
FileInfo origFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test.txt");
FileInfo destFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CopyTest\test2.txt");

if (origFile.Exists())
{
    // читаем первый файл
}
else if (destFile.Exists())
{
    //читаем второй файл
}
```

Если нужно прочитать данные из максимального количества файлов

```
if (origFile.Exists())
{
    // читаем первый файл
}
if (destFile.Exists())
{
    //читаем второй файл
}
```